# Running a Procedure from another Access Database

Tags: ms-access, vba

Is there another way to Run a Procedure from another Access Databases module other then opening the DataBase first. I could use this:

```
Dim appAccess As Access.Application
Set appAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")

appAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\Test\Test.mdb", False
appAccess.Run "CountTablesInDB"

Set appAccess = Nothing
```

But that opens the Database and causes my opening form for that DB to open up.

Comment: Do you just want to count the tables in the other database (_CountTablesInDB_)?

Comment: No that was just an example. The real question is whether or not a Procedure from another db can be called on with out having to open the database first.

Comment: Ah, ok.  I was going to give you some SQL to count the tables from the `MSysObjects` table in the other DB.  No good for running code though.  I can't imagine be able to run code in a closed database, but I could be wrong.

Comment: You might be able to create a _Reference_ to the remote database - for it to act as an add-in.

Comment: Do you have a link to the method?